# Android XML: SurfaceView layout height 16/9 of width?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I want the height of my surfaceview in xml to be depending on the width, so I would like something like this:

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="layout_width*16/9"
```

Is there a way to do this or how do I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do this in the XML - that's why I some time ago wrote a FixedAspectRatioImageView (a subclass of ImageView). It basically took another XML-Parameter ("16:9") and overrode onMeasure to always maintain the aspect ratio. I belive there explanations of how to do this here on SO, but if you don't find anything I can post my code here.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I dont need your code, thanks anyways.  :)

Comment: The typical approach is with a custom FrameLayout, e.g. https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java .